# Unity3d ошибка с переключением камер?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public Camera camera1;
public Camera camera2;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    camera1 = (Camera)(object)GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
    camera2 = GetComponent<Camera>();
    camera1.enabled = true;
    camera2.enabled = false;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
       camera2.enabled = !camera2.enabled;
        camera1.enabled = !camera1.enabled;
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    };
```

При запуске unity выдает такую ошибку -

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
>   CubeScript.Start () (at Assets/scripts/CubeScript.cs:12)
>   -Т.е оно ругается на строку

```
camera1 = (Camera)(object)GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
```

- из - за привидения типов, но по-другому преобразовать из GameObject в Camera у меня не выходит - т.к мне из двух камер на сцене в это поле нужно присвоить одну конкртную, а это же как я понимаю единственный способ получит ссылку на внешний объект?

И далее при нажатии соответствующей клавиши W 
возникает ошибка:

> nassignedReferenceException: The variable camera2 of CubeScript has not been assigned.
>   You probably need to assign the camera2 variable of the CubeScript script in the inspector.
>   CubeScript.Update () (at Assets/scripts/CubeScript.cs:23)
>   -почему unity говорит что значение для переменной camera2 не назначено? Ведь вот здесь -

```
camera2 = GetComponent<Camera>();
```

я присваивая ей значение - объект получает камеру которую я "повесил" на объект, а

`camera1 = (Camera)(object)GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");`

студия получает "главную камеру" - т.е у меня в сцене - две камеры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся ваша проблема заключается в строке, где вы ищете объект MainCamera:

> `camera1 = (Camera)(object)GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");`

Во-первых, `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag` возвращает тип `GameObject[]`, то есть массив, который у вас никогда не получится преобразовать к `Camera`, об этом можно почитать в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html). Вы можете исправить это если полученный результат (массив) проверите на количество элементов, то есть в вашем случае там должен быть 1 элемент и обратитесь именно к нему, то есть примерно так:

```
var goArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
var cameraGO = goArray[0];
```

и потом получите саму камеру на этом объекте, не по средствам приведения типов, а через `GetComponent<Camera>()`

Во-вторых, можете использовать метод [GameObject.FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html), что будет намного проще в вашем случае, так как он вернет 1 активный GameObject с указанным тэгом. Но у него все-равно надо будет вызывать `GetComponent<Camera>()`. Никакого преобразования типов не нужно.

Также если

> `camera2 = GetComponent<Camera>();`

выдает ошибку, то это может быть только в случае, если на GameObject, к которому прикреплен ваш скрипт, нет компонента Camera.