# Взаимодействие скрипта с другими объектами в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

На сцене есть Particle System  и куб. на кубе есть скрипт

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && gb.transform.rotation.x != 180 && gb.transform.rotation.y != 90)
    {


        gb.LookAt(Input.mousePosition);
        gb.Rotate(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0f),0f,Space.World);
```

-обычный поворот куба за мышью  - только теперь мне необхлжимо что бы Particle System появлялась также за мышью перед кубом
я думал как то так:

```
ParticleSystem PS;
 PS= GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Respawn");

if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && gb.transform.rotation.x != 180 && gb.transform.rotation.y != 90)
    {


        gb.LookAt(Input.mousePosition);
        gb.Rotate(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0f),0f,Space.World);
        PS.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
        PS.Play();

    }
```

Я уже задавал вопрос на SO и мине посоветовали [Unity3d ошибка с переключением камер?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704877/unity3d-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80)

-GameObject.FindWithTag
 - но FindWithTag - все равно возвращает GameObject а мне нужен тип Particle System - т.е вот в чем вопрос как мне получит ссылку на внешний объект на сцене например такой как Particle System не меняя его тип?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автор, `ParticleSystem` - это компонент. `GameObject` не наследуется в общем случае. Компоненты подцепляются под него. Поэтому тебе нужно найти твой `GameObject`, и у него уже искать компонент `ParticleSystem`

```
GameObject respawn = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Respawn");
ParticleSystem ps = (ParticleSystem)respawn.GetComponent(typeof(ParticleSystem));
```

Там наверняка есть перегрузка с `<T>`, используй её, но под рукой нет Unity, только документация. :)

Comment: ParticleSystem ps = (ParticleSystem)respawn.GetComponent(typeof(ParticleSystem));

не подскажите, а почему у меня тут возникает NullReferenceException?
Это при том что в GameObject respawn = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Respawn"); - тэг на объекте у меня присвоен
ну точнее ругается на
 ps.transform.position = Input.mouseScrollDelta;
но выдает именно NRE  - следовательно ругается на строку 
ParticleSystem ps = (ParticleSystem)respawn.GetComponent(typeof(ParticleSystem));

Comment: @BadCats пройди в отладчике, посмотри - кого не находит. Видимо, нет на сцене объекта с таким тегом. Или в имени тега ошибка. Кстати, такая запись не имеет смысла: `ps.transform.position`, так как у компонента нет собственного `Transform` и ты обращаешься к свойству родительского `GameObject`'а.